# What patriotic music might have been popular for Independence Day in 1866?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, american-civil-war, music

I am on a search for American patriotic music that would have been performed at a New England (specifically, Portland, Maine) Independence Day celebration in 1866.  I would like to find a list of several songs that might have been played or sung.  My first instincts were either well-known Civil War tunes, or Sousa marches.  At this time (according to Wikipedia at least) Civil War music was not in vogue.  And it is before the music of J.P. Sousa, who was only 12 in 1866.  So my instincts are wrong!

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_patriotic_music) says:

> During the events leading up to the American Civil War, both the North and the South generated a number of songs to stir up patriotic sentiments such as "Battle Hymn of the Republic", and "Dixie". However, after the Civil War, the sentiments of most patriotic songs were geared to rebuilding and consolidating the United States. During the Spanish–American War in the 1890s, songwriters continued to write patriotic tunes that honored America's soldiers and rallied citizens in support of the war.[5] Songs such as "Brave Dewey and His Men" and "The Charge of the Roosevelt Riders" lauded Commodore George Dewey and Theodore Roosevelt. Around this time, John Philip Sousa began composing many of his famous patriotic marches, including "The Stars and Stripes Forever" and "The Washington Post March." Songs such as "The Black KPs", likely labelled racist and offensive by modern listeners, were intended to rally the public behind the war effort.[5]

So, does anyone know where I might look to find a songbook or program listing a handful of songs that might have been heard in Portland on July 4, 1866?

Comment: People may have had other things on their mind than the singing of patriotic songs: " *1866, July 4, Portland (Maine). A cracker thrown by a boy during the celebration of Independence Day led to the destruction of nearly all the business portion of the city, including 8 churches, the banks, newspaper offices, etc. More that 2000 families homeless.* " (The Insurance Cyclopædia, Vol. 4. London: C. & E. Layton 1876, p. 98)

Comment: Haven't found anything yet specific to New England, but this was the musical program for the July 4, 1866 [celebrations in Philadelphia](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fourth_of_July_Souvenir_Containing_a_Suc/Jz9SdepQCJ0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA13&printsec=frontcover): " *1. .. Triumphal March ... 3. The Star Spangled Banner ... 6 .. Hallelujah. Handel. ... 8. Old Hundred ... 9. Coronation March -- Meyerbeer* " The "Old Hundred" is apparently an [old hymn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_100th).

Comment: @njuffa - "Old _Hundredth_" - an old translation of Psalm 100 into English verse.

Comment: @njuffa: Well done! What a find.

Comment: @njuffa most certainly they did.  I am aware of the great fire that happened amidst the revelry

Comment: @KateBunting  I quoted the publication accurately. Wikipedia says (my bolding): *"Old 100th" or "Old Hundredth" (also known as "**Old Hundred**") is a hymn tune in long metre* ...

Comment: @mjuffa That reads like an answer to me.

Comment: Sousa was born in November.  He was only 11 on independence day.

Comment: Well @phoog too young for Stars and Stripes Forever in any event

Comment: @nuggethead indeed. I've done a bit of research looking for more northerly concert programs with no luck so far.  One of the avenues I pursued was George Ives, whose 21st birthday was on August 3rd, 1866.  He was a bandleader in the Union army from the age of 17. (There's a story that U.S. Grant told Lincoln that he'd heard it was the best band in the army, saying, "I wouldn't know; I only know two songs: one’s Yankee Doodle, and the other ain’t.") George's son Charles was composing by age 14.

Comment: Sousa's father John Anthony (born João António), a trombonist in the Marine Band, enlisted John Philip as an apprentice musician at the age of 13. He [began composing by 1869](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compositions_by_John_Philip_Sousa) and published his first  march in 1873, the year of his 19th birthday.  All of which is, indeed, after 1866.